# Embed (internalize) java in your desktop application

Tags: java, installation, embed

I am trying to embed (internalize) java into the installation directory of my application. Looking at the documentation and all other help available that I could go through I copied the java directory to the application one and then set all the environment variables and paths as prescribed. However, when I launch the application using this new java directory it gives java not found error. Can someone give me some tips?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Wat platform is it? Have you tried printing path variable value on the command prompt?

Comment: @JSS - Yes. Everything is correct. Still no luck.

Comment: I you want a commercial tool, Advanced Installer supports JRE bundles for a Java application. Otherwise, you can try launching your application with a custom command line that uses your copied JRE files. Launching the main .jre directly doesn't recognize your copied JRE files automatically because you didn't actually install a JRE, you just copied its files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I launch the application using this new java directory it gives java not found error. Can someone give me some tips?

You've obviously not set up the %PATH% environment correctly.  That's what is causing whatever is launching Java to say "java not found".

You could:

- modify whatever is trying launching Java to print out the environment variables, or
- change whatever is trying launching Java to use the absolute pathname for the "java" command.

Comment: I have tried checking the environment variables many times over and over and it is correct. I have also already tried absolute path name several times and still no luck. Funny thing is if i change everything back to the installed version of java it starts working fine. I know i am missing something stupid but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you good luck in this task but may I ask you why do you want to do this? If you really wish to put java under your application install java there. You can use silent mode of installation. I do not remember the syntax right now but if you are on windows, java is installed by Windows installer, so search for "run windows installer silently" and follow the instructions. I believe that this approach will work on better and easier.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am already using is at a silent install. However, sometimes the customers have complained problems with other apps that use another version of java already installed on the same system. So rather than have it mess up some other application, i thought it would be a better option to embed the directory and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source to WinRun4J (alternative to javaw on windows) and see how they initialize the JVM.

Comment: Nothing useful there. It has C, C++ and VC files in the source code.

Comment: @Ali Actually look at what the c/c++ files do. They contain an algorithm to locate a jvm dll either as a system JVM (c:\program files\\) or a sub-folder (.\jvm\lib\jvm.dll ?). It shows how to load the jvm.dll from a specified path and then kick off main from within C.